# PHP unable to load dynamic library's library

Tags: php, php5, pecl, imagemagick

I have been trying to get imagick to work on a normal lamp server. What I did:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove "imagemagick"
sudo apt-get --purge remove "php5-imagick*"

service apache2 restart (lib not loaded anymore)

sudo apt-get install imagemagick && php5-imagick
sudo php5enmod imagick
sudo service apache2 restart
```

The PHP info tells that the lib is loaded, but the apache error log is spammed with the following for every request:

`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/imagick.so' - liblcms2.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0`

The file `/usr/lib/php5/20121212/imagick.so` exists, if I delete it, the error is the same, but with `[..]imagick.so' - imagick.so[..]` instead of `[..]imagick.so' - liblcms2.so.2[..]`

**PHP Version:** 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14

Comment: It seems that you need to install the package `lcms2`

Comment: Thanks that helped me track down the issue, although I already reinstalled it before. But I looked into what it is installing and found out that it creates a file called `liblcms2.so.2.0.5` and a symlink `liblcms2.so` pointing to it. So I created another symlink ( `liblcms2.so.2` ) and it worked.